# recreating a store in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, rss, e-commerce

I have a friend that refuses to buy a responsive design from the cart software provider (pinnacle cart), and he wants me to recreate the store in iOS...

the only way I can think of doing this is to parse an RSS feed into a list view and use a web view to complete the purchase...anything that I've thought of so far is going to be sloppy looking...any suggestions?

Can i inject CSS into a web view to make it more phone friendly?

Has anyone taken the long way around like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i inject CSS into a web view to make it more phone friendly?

Since the web view merely renders a web page - yes. Just put all your HTML/CSS/JS files in the iOS project, but pay attention to the paths you use to reference stylesheets and script files.

Example:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"foo" withExtension:@"html"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

loads foo.html from your application. Put the CSS files in the same directory as the HTML file and you can include it via relative paths, like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks guys. i might just have to force him to get an adaptive template and use a webview. THis is going to be too much work for little reward...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Phonegap either with jquery library or Sencha Touch instead of Using a Webview if you Use it Directly in a webview, It would be hard for you to get the app in app store.